# How do I change facebook messenger bot webhook?

Tags: facebook, webhooks, facebook-messenger

I have successfully implemented a facebook bot. It's working fine. I was trying to change the webhook url now as I have to port it to a different server with a new domain.

There is an option to change the events but I could not find and option to change the webhook. How do I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can't edit the link directy from the "Messenger" product. 
On the left menu, after selecting your application, you have to click "+ add product" and add also webhooks.
From webhooks then you can edit also messenger's webhook.

To edit the webhook, click on `Edit Subscription` button on the page. Make sure that the dropdown at the top has the option `Page` selected. 
[image]

Comment: Ah at last I found it. Thanks for your answer. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: When you click the webhooks  as shown above, you will see a edit subscription button, click on it and you will be shown with screen where you can edit your parameters and then click verify and save

Comment: How long does the change take to be in effect? I changed it and keep getting a reply from the old server.

Comment: @FernandoAndré How long did it take? I've been waiting for 15h, and it's always linking with the old webhooks.

Comment: @Neabfi just put ur app in development mode and publish again..this works for me :)

Comment: Nice gem!! Saved me a lot of time!

Comment: I don't have 'Page' as an option.

Comment: @Matt : same here, it was there before, but disappeared somewhere last week. Changed it manually by doing a POST request to the subscriptions (More information here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/subscriptions). Before you can do this, you need to generate an application access token first: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens

Answer (score 4):

Besides setting from UI, you can also use `subscriptions` API to achieve this:

Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/subscriptions

For example:

```
POST /v2.12/{app-id}/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

object=page&callback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback%2F&fields=about%2C+picture&include_values=true&verify_token=thisisaverifystring
```

`callback_url` is what you want to change.
Make sure you have correct `field` and `verify_token` setting too.

Answer (score 3):

You can change webhook under "webhooks" in menu (picture).

[image]

Comment: Can't find that menu. Did someone find a solution to change webhook's url?

Comment: goto this url : https://developers.facebook.com/apps/558392797857560/messenger/settings/