# Changing webhook url of facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-messenger-bot

I'd like to update the webhook URL of my facebook messenger bot. [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook) sais:

> In the Webhooks settings, click the 'Edit Subscriptions' button.
>   Update your webhook details.

but I have no this option. Then I was following the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685220/how-do-i-change-facebook-messenger-bot-webhook) to change the URL, but I have no page option either.

How am I able to replace the webhook URL?
The bot itself works, I'm the administrator of it, can send and receive message using it.
Thank you.

**Update**: 
I tried to update the URL using the API but I got the following response.
The access token is correct and I can read the endpoint.

```
 {
    "error": {
        "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 200,
        "fbtrace_id": "AeVAghw8lxe"
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check their bug tracker and see if this was reported already, if not, do so. In the meantime you can update your webhook settings via API as well, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/app/subscriptions You can go through those steps in Graph API Explorer, if you don't want to do any actual coding for this.

Comment: thanks for the comment, the graph api works if I want to read, but not at writing. Are there some days that I need to wait after I created the app?
When I googled for this issue found these related ones. Updated my post.

Comment: _"the graph api works if I want to read, but not at writing"_ - nonsense, then it would not say _"Use this edge to read, create, update, and delete Webhooks subscriptions"_ right on top of that page.

Comment: yes, get works, post request does not,  post returns with (#200) Permissions error at writing

Answer (score 2):

The option is in Webhooks. The default option in the dropdown menu is "User". That page has an "Edit Subscription" button where you can change your webhook url.

[image: Image of facebook options panel]

Answer (score 1):

got a similar error, maybe it's regarding the issue

(#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active accounts due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform